# How to align Div correctly

Tags: css

I would like to create such Div structure

```
--------div-container-------
----------div-menu----------
--div-title--|--div-submenu-


<div class="div-container">
  <div class="div-menu">
  </div>
  <div class="div-content">
     <div class="div-title"> 
     </div>
     <div class="div-submenu">
     </div> 
  <div>
</div>
```

The problem is that I do not know how to set div-menu to take the whole row and div-title and div-submenu put on the same row. I have tried to set float:left for div-title and float:right for div-submenu but these divs then takes the space from div-menu.

Comment: Look at my example, probably your float:left didn't work because you also have to set their height to half (at least, considering also margins and paddings) the size of their parent element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Div is a block element so it takes entire horizontal space 


And to make two divs come side by side use style "display:inline-block" for "div-title " and "div-menu" .
display:inline-block works for IE7 +/FF

For IE7 and below use below css to behave like inline-block
selector { 
    zoom:1;
   *display:inline;
}
```

Comment: Your solution is the clearest one and works as intended. Float property brings many issues in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this, hope it helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/Xrqxc/12/

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .div-menu {
        background: #ccddee;
    }
    .div-title {
        float: left;
        background: #ddeeff;
        width: 50%;
    } 
    .div-submenu {
        float: right;
        background: #eeffff;
        width: 50%;
    } 
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="div-container">
      <div class="div-menu">
        Foo
      </div>
      <div class="div-content">
         <div class="div-title"> 
            Bar
         </div>
         <div class="div-submenu">
            Baz
         </div> 
      <div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In case you want borders etc. in one of the container div elements and you run into float containment issue, I've documented a couple of fixes here: http://notes.susam.in/2011/06/float-containment.html

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example

http://jsfiddle.net/PjYF8/